# Concat two column in a select statement sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, concatenation

How to Concat two column in a select statement sql server 2005?

Here is my statement `Select FirstName,secondName from Table`...

Now i did try concating `secondName` with `FirstName` by using

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + secondName from Table
```

But some values are `NULL` in secondName column for some records.. My select statement 
returns `NULL` instead of `FirstName`.. I want to have `FirstName` if secondName is `NULL` ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SELECT FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + SecondName, '') from Table`

Answer (score 0):

If one of your fields is numeric then you can cast it to a `string` as follows:

```
SELECT FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + SecondName, '') + ' age(' + CONVERT(nvarchar,age) + ')' from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this :

```
 select cast( FirstName as varchar)+' '+cast( secondName as varchar) from table
```