# Select Sql Query from 2 column into one column

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
 empid  empname  empDOB
  1      kiran    23-11-1987
  2      manu     25-4-1999
```

now i need to  write 1 single query where  empname and empDOB as single value

```
 empid Emp
  1    kiran,23-11-1987
  2    manu ,25-4-1999
```

i need  the  output like this

can  anyone please tel me the syntax how to  do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137835/concat-two-column-in-a-select-statement-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the values together like this:

```
SELECT empid, ISNULL(empname, '') + ',' + ISNULL(empDOB, '') AS emp
FROM YourTable
```

If empDOB is a DATETIME field, you could do this which will format the date in the format you've given:

```
SELECT empid, ISNULL(empname, '') + ',' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), empDOB, 105), '') AS emp
FROM YourTable
```