# SQL Searching Part of a Sentence in Two Fields Simultaniously

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In my MSSQL table I have **two fields**, first one is `post_name` (position at job) and another filed is `org_name` (names or location of organizations). I'm writting a PHP script to seach through those two fields. I use Select2 Bootstrap plugin which is basically a seach line with dropdown options fetched from the database based on what user is typing in.

A user usually search for full job title including `post_name` and `org_name`. Let's say "Chief Sales Manager Toronto" where first 3 words are from first field and the last word is from second field. When a user start typing Chief Sales Man..." he should be alble to get the whole list of such managers in Toronto, Cupertino or whatever.

The SELECT query I use for this is:

```
SELECT post_name, org_name 
FROM table 
WHERE post_name LIKE 'searchTerm%';
```

That gives me the needed job titles only if I didn't start typing the org name as obviously then it tries to find the whole sentence in post_name filed and gives an empty string.

I also tried:

```
SELECT post_name, org_name 
FROM table 
WHERE post_name LIKE 'searchTerm%' OR org_name LIKE '%searchTerm%';
```

or I was trying to split the searchTerm and try to seach in org_name field by using end of searchTerm:

```
SELECT post_name, org_name 
FROM table 
WHERE post_name LIKE 'searchTerm%' 
    AND org_name LIKE '%.substr(searchTerm, -6).%';
```

But the last ones are even more pathetic. I was thinking of using CONCAT to unite those two fields so I can search in those two as one, something like

```
SELECT CONCAT(post_name, org_name) as full_title
FROM table 
WHERE full_title LIKE 'searchTerm%';
```

But in MSSQL Server Express 2005 I get an error of non existing function.

Is there any way I could search such a one sentence in those two fields simultaniously?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve (intelligent search) is not possible that way.

1. What if a user searches for **Toronto Chief sales manager**

Which means you'll search **manager** on the **org_name** field

2. Are you going to restrict users or even possibly ask them to input the org_name as the last word?

You can as well just provide 2 fields for the search form

Comment: @Spikes All this is correct. Fortunatelly all my user know that "Toronto" should be at the end, it is in the manual for using the system so the found answer fits.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the question is clearly about SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you want in SQL Server seems to be:

```
SELECT post_name, org_name
FROM table 
WHERE post_name + org_name  LIKE 'searchTerm%';
```

You might want to include a space between the columns as well.

That said, you might want to look into full text search capabilities.  It might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: That's a simpler one so I have switched to this solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your last query would work like this

```
SELECT post_name, org_name
FROM (
       SELECT post_name, org_name,
       CONCAT(post_name,' ', org_name) as full_title
       FROM table 
) z
WHERE full_title LIKE 'searchTerm%';
```

Comment: Thank yoy very much. The concat didn't work for my version of SQL server but I found a solution here: [Concat two column in a select statement sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137835/concat-two-column-in-a-select-statement-sql-server-2005). I put it together and it is working exactly as needed.